# Is it safe to use redirect after login

Tags: php, session, redirect, save, login-script

I am creating a login script in PHP and I am just wondering if it is safe to redirect a user who is not logged in? I am checking the session and if the user is not logged in I want to use something like:

```
session_start();
//check session
if (user is not logged in)
    header ("Location: login.php"); 
//content of confidential file
```

Can the user somehow prevent the redirection and see the content or will the script stop and redirect no matter what the users does? I want to perform this check on every confidential page I have.

Thanks to all, I will use:

```
session_start();
//check if user is logged in
if(!check)
{
      header ("Location: login.php");
      die("Please <a href=\"login.php\">log in</a>");
}
//print all the html stuff only logged it users should see
```

Thanks for all the help!
Nick

Comment: If you [`exit`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) immediately afterward, it is safe.

Comment: Add a die() after the header?

Comment: Oh yeah,I forgot to ask about exit(). So that will be enough? Is there a difference between die(); and exit(); ?

Comment: Technically speaking. No

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: Why you didnt include http 3xx redirect code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will be redirected before any of the data is rendered. Just to be sure, make sure you put that code before any HTML or displaying anything.

Comment: You also need to be sure to stop further execution of the script.  A Location: header is more of a recommendation to the client, so if you follow it with confidential data it could still be received by a client that chooses to ignore the header.

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();
//check session
if (user is not logged in) {
    header ("Location: login.php"); 
    die();
}
//content of confidential file
```

will solve your problem :)

Comment: Well you need to add a pair of {}

Comment: That will still print the content of the confidential file, as written.